# Gibrish when fetching an image and sending to client

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In my server i read an image - jpg -  from a url with :

```
        let _uri = "https.....xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg";

        let _headers = {
          'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
              'Accept-Encoding': '*',
              'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en',
              'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
              'Connection': 'keep-alive',
              'Referer': 'http://www.google.com/',
              'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
              'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
        }


        var options = {
            uri: _uri,
            headers: _headers
        };

        rp(options)
            .then(parsedBody => {
               //response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
              //  return response.status(200).send(parsedBody);  //** don't work also
              return response.json(parsedBody);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                response.status(400).send(err)
            });

    });
```

No matter what i try, this will get a huge chunk of garbage when i check the response.
I can't find out what type of data is it.

On client i receive it - again - a lot of jibrish :

```
 fetch('https://...my server')
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => {
       console.log(blob);
```

How do i get this photo on server and send to client ?

Comment: If it's an image you don't need to wrap it with json, you can send it back immediately. Pass `encoding: null` as option to force it to return a `Buffer`. Also at your client you can not `console.log` binary data and expect the output to make sense. You can just put the whole url in `src` attribute of `<img>` or test it by entering the url in your browser

Comment: thanks a lot for all your comments. Well, even if i return a blob right away, and even if i open the url in the browser, what i get is :  {} .   I am struggling for 2 days with this simple thing.

Comment: Have you tried `options = {  uri: _uri, headers: _headers, encoding: null }` and do `response.setHeader` and `response.send` as the code in the code comment? I notice you posted a similar post with `fetch` on server. I think using the approach on this post is more straightforward

Comment: If you could please show, any sort of example how exactly i can send this image back to client, i will be insanly grateful since NOTHING i do work. the size is 0. The url is a valid photo.

Comment: I tried your comment here , it worked !!!!!!!!! thanks you !!!!!!!!!!!! please post an answer so i can accept and vote you ! @TheeSritabtim

Comment: I have posted an answer. Feel free to mark as accepted if you think it’s helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an option `encoding: null` to have the response returned as `Buffer`

```
var options = {
  uri: _uri,
  headers: _headers,
  encoding: null // add this line
}
```

Then you can just send the buffer as response

```
rp(options)
  .then(buffer => {
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
    return response.status(200).send(buffer);
  })
```